# CMake error with custom messages

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, python2.7

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created 2 custom messages in my package to publish data through one of my nodes. The .msg files are:

bearing_angles.msg

```
float left_edge
float right edge
```

bearArray.msg

```
bearArray[] bear_array
```

I changes my CMakeLists.txt of my package, so it looks like this:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  message_generation
)

add_message_files(
  FILES
  Num.msg
  bearing_angles.msg
  bearArray.msg
)

generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs
)

catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES door_detector_1
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs message_runtime
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)
```

But when I build my package from catkin_ws directory, with catkin_make, I get this error:

```
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/msg_loader.py", line 326, in load_msg_depends
    load_msg_depends(msg_context, depspec, search_path)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/msg_loader.py", line 315, in load_msg_depends
    depspec = msg_context.get_registered(resolved_type)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/msg_loader.py", line 439, in get_registered
    if self.is_registered(full_msg_type):
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/msg_loader.py", line 428, in is_registered
    package, base_type = package_resource_name(full_msg_type)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/names.py", line 104, in package_resource_name
    val = tuple(name.split(PRN_SEPARATOR))
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  
  execute_process(/home/spyros/catkin_ws/build/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh
  "/usr/bin/python2" "/usr/bin/empy" "--raw-errors" "-F"
  "/home/spyros/catkin_ws/build/door_detector_1/cmake/door_detector_1-genmsg-context.py"
  "-o"
  "/home/spyros/catkin_ws/build/door_detector_1/cmake/door_detector_1-genmsg.cmake"
  "/opt/ros/melodic/share/genmsg/cmake/pkg-genmsg.cmake.em") returned error
  code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/em_expand.cmake:25 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:303 (em_expand)
  door_detector_1/CMakeLists.txt:74 (generate_messages)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/spyros/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/spyros/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:768: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

I think I miss something in the CMakeLists.txt file, but I didn't find it so far. What am I missing here? Any feedback is appreciated.

I use Ubuntu 18, ROS melodic, and my node is written in python 2.7

UPDATE (CMake error): After @gvdhoorn answer

```
CMake Error at /home/spyros/catkin_ws/build/door_detector_1/cmake/door_detector_1-genmsg.cmake:3 (message):
  Could not find messages which
  '/home/spyros/catkin_ws/src/door_detector_1/msg/bearing_angles.msg' depends
  on.  Did you forget to specify generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)?

  Cannot locate message [float] in package [door_detector_1] with paths
  [['/home/spyros/catkin_ws/src/door_detector_1/msg']]
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:307 (include)
  door_detector_1/CMakeLists.txt:74 (generate_messages)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/spyros/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/spyros/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:768: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372093/cmake-error-with-custom-messages/) by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2021-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I think I miss something in the CMakeLists.txt file, but I didn't find it so far.

No, there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your `CMakeLists.txt`.

It's most likely this:

> The .msg files are:
>
> bearing_angles.msg
>
> ```
> float left_edge
> ```

```
float right edge
```

> bearArray.msg
>
> ```
> bearArray[] bear_array
> ```

notice how you've given the `bear_array` field the type "unbounded array of `bearArray`".

In words: a `bearArray` message has a single field, which is an array of `bearArray` messages.

You've defined a `bearArray` messages in terms of itself, which we also call "recursion", which leads to:

> ```
> RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
> ```

Did you actually mean to use `bearing_angles[] bear_array`?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on 2021-02-18**:
yes, I want to use a `bearArray` message, which is an array of `bearing_angles` messages. Is this the right way? `bearing_angles[] bear_array`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-18**:
yes.

As I suggested at the end of my answer.

note btw that `bear_array` to me sounds like an array of [bears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bear), which is probably not what this is going to be about.

**Comment by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on 2021-02-18**:
Not really handy name indeed. I changed my .msg file as you suggested, and I got a new cmake error after building (check updated post)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-18**:\

> ```
> Cannot locate message [float] in package [door_detector_1] with paths
> ```

this is unrelated to your previous error.

`float` is not a valid field type. Only `float32` or `float64` are valid.

See [wiki/msg](http://wiki.ros.org/msg#Fields).

**Comment by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on 2021-02-18**:
this solved and my last error. Now my package is built without problems. Thanks!